# Calculate $\int\int_S\vec F\cdot\vec ndS$, where $\vec F(x,y,z)=-z\vec k$ and $S$ is the part of $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ outside of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: calculus

Calculate $\int\int_S\vec F\cdot\vec ndS$, where $\vec F(x,y,z)=-z\vec k$ and $S$ is the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ outside of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$, with $\vec n$ pointing out of the sphere.

Answer: $-4\pi\sqrt3$

My attempt:

$x^2+y^2+z^2=4$

$x^2+y^2=1$

$1+z^2=4$

$z^2=3$

$z=\pm\sqrt3$

$2\cos\phi=\pm\sqrt3$

$\phi=\pm\cos^{-1}\frac{\sqrt3}{2}=\pm\frac{\pi}{6}$

$\vec r(\phi,\theta)=(2\sin\phi\cos\theta,2\sin\phi\sin\theta,2\cos\phi)$

$\frac{\pi}{6}\leq\phi\leq\frac{5\pi}{6},0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$

$\vec r_{\phi}\times\vec r_{\theta}=4\sin^2\phi\cos\theta\vec i+4\sin^2\phi\sin\theta\vec j+4\sin\phi\cos\phi\vec k$

$\int\int_S\vec F\cdot\vec n dS=\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6}\int_0^{2\pi}(0,0,-1)\cdot(4\sin^2\phi\cos\theta,4\sin^2\phi\sin\theta,4\sin\phi\cos\phi)4\sin\phi d\theta d\phi$

$=\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6}\int_0^{2\pi}-16sin^2\phi\cos\theta d\theta d\phi$

$=0$

I'm not sure if the bounds of $\phi$ are correct or if even I should be using spherical coordinates, but beyond that everything else seems right to me, help me understand what is going wrong here.

Comment: Where did the $(0,0,-1)$ come from? P.S. Your limits seem fine.

Comment: It's the coordinates from the vector field, but now I realize that's in cartesian coordinates, I forgot to change to spherical coordinates, but I think changing wouldn't change the result since the inside integral still 0.

Comment: It’s $-z\vec k$, isn’t it?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=2$ (sphere) and $r=1$ (cylinder).

$$\vec{F}=(0,0,-z)$$
$$\vec{n}=\frac{(x,y,z)}{R}$$
$$\vec{F} \cdot\vec{n}=-\frac{z^2}{R}$$
$$dS=R \ d\phi dz \text{ (cylindrical coordinates)}$$
$$\int\int_S\vec F\cdot\vec ndS=\int _{-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}\int _0^{2 \pi }\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}\ R d\phi dz=\int _{-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}\int _0^{2 \pi }-z^2\ d\phi dz=-\frac{4}{3} \pi  \left(R^2-r^2\right)^{3/2}$$
$$-\frac{4}{3} \pi  \left(R^2-r^2\right)^{3/2}|_{R=2,r=1}=-4 \sqrt{3} \pi$$